# Is it possible to enforce constness of passed dependency object in c++

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, constants

Here is what I would like to prevent:

```
class Dep; //for "dependency"

class C {
  private: 
    const Dep& dep_; //or std::shared_ptr if I want to guarantee proper lifetime of dependency
  public:
    C(const Dep& dep) : dep_(dep){}
}

Dep d(Arg arg);
C obj(d); //obj can't change d
d.some_non_const_method(); //But it's creator can :(
```

What I would like to get is that the only correct way to create `C` object was like this:

```
Dep d(Arg arg);
d.some_non_const_method();
const Dep d1(d); //or move constructor if appropriate
C obj(d1); //Object d1 must be const!
d1.some_non_const_method(); //compile error, so obj can be sure that the dependency he's got is really const.
```

Is there any way to enforce this via syntax?

P.S. Dependency is intended to be shared, so I can't use `std::unique_ptr` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that there is a way to enforce this directly via syntax.

The problem is that any `Dep&` may be converted freely to a `const Dep&`. As you correctly noted taking a `const Dep &d` does not mean that is constant, rather it is a promise that your function will never modify `d`.

While the other answers ingeniously use overloading and deleted methods to create an error whenever a non-const Dep is passed directly, these methods fail, when a `const Dep &` is passed from elsewhere.

```
// this could be arbitrarily complex and nested
std::unique_ptr<C> makeC(const Dep &d) {
     return std::make_unique<C>(d);
} 

void test() {
    Dep nonConstDep;
    auto pC = makeC(nonConstD); // conversion to const & is legal
    nonConstDep.mutate(); // Nooo!
}
```

What you need is an immutable dep class that does not allow mutation and conversion.

Since I do not know whether you may change the `Dep` class and how you use it in other parts of your program, I suggest this solution:

Create an `ImmutableDep` wrapper, that has a private `const Dep`. Then you could restrict your class to only take ImmutableDep references.

```
class ImmutableDep {
     const Dep dep_;

public:
     inline const Dep &get() const { return dep_; }
};

class C {
     const Dep &dep_;
public:
     // we know that an ImmutableDep's dep really is immutable
     C(const ImmutableDep &dep) : dep_(dep.get()) {}
}
```

This way you can pass around const or non-const references to `ImmutableDep` as much as you like, you are always guaranteed that the private wrapped `Dep` is immutable.

If you need to modify `Dep` only during a limited "construction" phase, I suggest using the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) and create an immutable object after you are done, perhaps moving anything large into the the immutable object.

Comment: You could simply make `Immutable` a template, add a few ctors, and it can be used more widely...

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to only accept a `const` argument, and want to get an error if a non-`const` argument is passed.

The simplest way should be marking the non-`const` version as `delete`:

```
class C {
  private:
    const Dep& dep_;
  public:
    C(const Dep& dep) : dep_(dep){}
    C(Dep &) = delete;
};
```

Then:

```
Dep d;
C obj(d); // Error, deleted function selected

const Dep d1(d);
C obj(d1); // ok
```

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work against deliberate misuse, or a const Dep& being passed from elsewhere: `C obj(const_cast<const Dep &>(d)) // haha`.

Comment: The problem is that creating a const & from a non-const object is allowed, and you can not really differentiate where a const reference came from: `std::unique_ptr<C> makeC(const Dep &d) {
    return std::make_unique<C>(d);
}` `makeC(nonConstD);`

Answer (score 1):

Something of the form

```
class C
{
    C() = default;
    friend class D;
};

class D
{
    public:
    C create_C() = delete;
    C create_C() const {return C};
};
```

would do it. I've made the construction of `C` `private`. `D` can access it though since it's a `friend` of `C`. The non-`const` overload of `create_C` is deleted.